# Problem with receiving SMS on smpplib Python

Tags: python, smpp

Problem with receiving SMS with latin characters, when I use command pdu.short_message.decode('utf-8') everything before latin character is trimmed. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Hardware is goip4 with enabled smpp server 
I try with python 3.6 and 3.7 same problem

Code is from internet but same code I use on my project.

```
logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')
client = smpplib.client.Client('123.456.789.101', 1123)
def getPdu(pdu):
    print(pdu.short_message.decode('utf-8'))
client.set_message_received_handler(getPdu)
client.connect()
client.bind_transceiver(system_id='1234', password='5678')
parts, encoding_flag, msg_type_flag = smpplib.gsm.make_parts('Руский из питона 3, кодировочку зажги!\n')
for part in parts:
    pdu = client.send_message(
        source_addr_ton=smpplib.consts.SMPP_TON_NWSPEC,
        source_addr_npi=smpplib.consts.SMPP_NPI_ISDN,
        source_addr='1591',
        dest_addr_ton=smpplib.consts.SMPP_TON_NATNL,
        dest_addr_npi=smpplib.consts.SMPP_NPI_ISDN,
        # Make sure thease two params are byte strings, not unicode:
        destination_addr='79531498486',
        short_message=part,
        data_coding=encoding_flag,
        esm_class=msg_type_flag,
        registered_delivery=True,
    )
    print(pdu.sequence)
client.listen()
```

Comment: did you try to decode with "CP1252" insted of decodign with "utf-8"
The documentation should mention how the sms is encoded.

Comment: yes, I try every combination I found on internet but without success. This is what I get 
b'\x00T\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00 \x00p\x00o\x00r\x00u\x01a\x00k\x00a'

Comment: I found solution ... string.decode('utf-16-be') ... thanks everyone